# API provides pagination functionality - client wants to query beyond bounds of API

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture

For a web project, I am consuming an API that returns Educational Materials (books, videos, etc) -- in simplicity you can request:

API accepted parameters :

**type**: accepts 1 or many: [book, video, software]
**subject matter**: accepts 1 or many:  [science, math, english, history]
**per page**: accepts an integer, defaults to 2, 0 returns ALL results
**page**: accepts an integer, defaults to 1

**Important**: This is a contrived example of a real use case, so it's not just 1 or 2 requests I'd have to cache, it's almost an infinite amount of combinations.

and it returns objects that look like:

```
{
    "total-results": 15,
    "page": 1,
    "per-page": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "Foobar",
            "type": "book",
            "subject-matter": [
                "history",
                "science"
            ],
            "age": 10
        },
        {
            "title": "Barfoo",
            "type": "video",
            "subject-matter": [
                "history"
            ],
            "age": 14
        }
    ]
}
```

The client wants to be able to allow users to filter by age  on my site -- so I have to essentially query everything and re-run my pagination.

I'd like to suggest to the API team (which we control) to allow me to query by age as well, but trying to explain this concept to the business is proving fruitless.

Right now all that I can think to solve this are 2 options: (1) convince the API team to allow me to query by age or (2) to cache the life out of my requests and use "0" by default and handle pagination on my end.

Again, **Important**: This is a contrived example of a real use case, so it's not just 1 or 2 requests I'd have to cache, it's almost an infinite amount of combinations.

Anyone have experience dealing with something similar to this?

Edit: Eric Stein asked a very sound question, here is the Q & A:

His Q: "Your API team does not know how to filter by age?"
My A: "They may it's a HUGE organization and I may get stonewalled because of bureaucracy and want to prepare for the worst."

Comment: Your API team does not understand the concept of filtering a response by age?

Comment: It's more bureaucracy than anything. I want to prepare for the worst.

Comment: This is a problem that needs to be solved at the API layer. Trying to cache responses locally and use that to simulate an age filter is a fool's errand unless your data set is small enough you can keep the whole library in local cache, in which case it only becomes prohibitively expensive to develop.

Comment: Thanks. I apprecaite the feedback

Comment: Wish I had better news for you, but this seems like an issue for your boss to take up with the API team.

Answer (score 0):

I worked in a project that we consumed an API and had to make more filters that the API allowed (the API wasn't ours). In that case what we decided was to create a cron script that consumed the API and registered the returned data in an database of our own. We had a lot of problems maintaining that (it was A LOT of data), but kinda worked for us (at least for the time I was working in the project).

I think if it's important to your application (and for your client) that you can age filter, that's a pretty good argument to convince the API team to allow that.